# How to read JSON file from resources in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-micrometer

Using Spring Boot 2.1.5 Release, have created the following sample Spring Boot Microservice:

Maven Project Structure:

```
MicroService
    │
    pom.xml
    src
    │
    └───main
        │ 
        ├───java
        │   │ 
        │   └───com
        │       └───microservice
        │           │
        │           └───MicroServiceApplication.java  
        │  
        └───resources
            │
            └───data.json
                │                    
                application.properties
```

Have the following JSON file (inside src/main/resources/data.json):

```
{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}
```

MicroServiceApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroServiceApplication {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            String data = FilePathUtils.readFileToString("../src/main/resources/data.json", MicroServiceApplication.class);
            System.out.println(data);
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Throws the following exception:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
  ...
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream is null
```

FilePathUtils.java:

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.util.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class FilePathUtils {
    public static String readFileToString(String path, Class aClazz) throws IOException {

        try (InputStream stream = aClazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)) {
            if (stream == null) {
                throw new IOException("Stream is null");
            }
            return IOUtils.toString(stream, Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I possibly being doing wrong?

Comment: Here you can find out the right solution [Stackoverflow read json from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676976/read-json-file-from-resources-and-convert-it-into-json-string-in-java/75685645#75685645)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While @Deadpool has provided the answer, I would like to add that when the artifact of spring boot is created there is no such `src/main/` folder anymore (you can open the spring boot artifact and make sure by yourself).

So you **can't** load resources like this:

```
FilePathUtils.readFileToString("../src/main/resources/data.json", MicroServiceApplication.class);
```

Spring indeed has an abstraction called `Resource` that can be used in the application, that can even be injected into the classes / configuration:

```
@Value("classpath:data/data.json")
Resource resourceFile;
```

Notice the prefix "classpath" it means that the resource will be resolved from the classpath (read everything properly packaged into the artifact).

There is a pretty good [Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access) that can be handy

Comment: thank you, I liked the `@Value("classpath:data/data.json")` annotation. :)

Comment: What is `Resource`? `javax.faces.application.Resource`?

Comment: @e-info128 https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html

Answer (score 15):

In spring boot project you can use `ResourceUtils`

```
Path file = ResourceUtils.getFile("data/data.json").toPath();
```

or `ClassPathResource`

```
String clsPath =  new ClassPathResource("data/data.json").getPath();
```

Sometimes if you are reading different extension file like `.graphql` or `.mmdb` or `.json` you need to read it as `InputStream` using spring `ResourceLoader`, this [article](https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/) has clear explanation

```
@Autowire
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

   Resource resource =resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");
   InputStream dbAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

And copy the `InputStream` to temp file using `Files.copy`

```
Files.copy(inputStream, outputFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: As per https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html it is mainly for internal use.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`jackson-databind`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) library.

The Jackson `ObjectMapper` class (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`) is one of the simplest way to parse `JSON`. The Jackson ObjectMapper `can parse JSON` from a string, stream or file, and `create a Java object or object graph` representing the parsed JSON. `Parsing JSON` into Java objects is also referred to as to `deserialize Java objects` from JSON.

```java
// create Object Mapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// read JSON file and map/convert to java POJO
try {
    SomeClass someClassObject = mapper.readValue(new File("../src/main/resources/data.json"), SomeClass.class);
    System.out.println(someClassObject);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and you shoud have `jackson-databind` in your `.pom` file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.4</version>
</dependency>
```