# Spring boot - Accessing firebase admin sdk credentials json file from inside a jar

Tags: java, spring, firebase-admin

I have a Java Spring Boot backend application that uses Firebase Admin SDK. inside the init method for FirebaseConfig I have to supply the credentials file for the FirebaseOptions,

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    FileInputStream refreshToken = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/progresee-fa969-firebase-adminsdk-3vip2-d80bf340b7.json");
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(refreshToken))
        .setDatabaseUrl(dbUrl)
        .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
}
```

everything works fine when I run locally, but when I build the jar file and upload to the server hosting service(AWS) I get a FileNotFound error -

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /progresee-fa969-firebase-adminsdk-3vip2-d80bf340b7.json (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at com.progresee.app.firebase.FirebaseConfig.init(FirebaseConfig.java:55) ~[classes!/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
... 74 common frames omitted
```

I tried to upload the file to a s3 bucket or firebase and to access it via URL but that way doesn't even work locally.

Thanks in advance,
Chen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOException When Trying to Load JSON data file via Spring Boot Command Line Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703834/ioexception-when-trying-to-load-json-data-file-via-spring-boot-command-line-runn)

Comment: Still gets the same error

Answer (score 3):

For adding the JSON configuration in the fat jar, please follow these steps.

1. Place the JSON file in `src/main/resources`
2. Inject the resource loader in Service

   ```java
   @Autowired
   ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
   ```
3. Get the inputstream of the resource instead of getting the file

   ```java
   Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:firebaseFile.json");    
   InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
   ```
4. Pass the inputstream in firebase option

Comment: with: `.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))` :)