# Read json file from resources and convert it into json string in JAVA

Tags: java, json, configuration

I have this JSON string hardcoded in my code.

```
String json = "{\n" +
              "    \"id\": 1,\n" +
              "    \"name\": \"Headphones\",\n" +
              "    \"price\": 1250.0,\n" +
              "    \"tags\": [\"home\", \"green\"]\n" +
              "}\n"
;
```

I want to move this to resources folder and read it from there,
How can I do that in JAVA?

Comment: Do you have constraints on libraries or framework to use? Please add more detail to let the people help you better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try(InputStream inputStream =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(Constants.MessageInput)){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(inputStream ,
                    JsonNode.class);
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Comment: @jschnasse damn, feels bad...

Answer (score 18):

This - in my experience - is the most reliable pattern to read files from class path.[1]

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("YourJsonFile")
```

It gives you an `InputStream` [2] which can be passed to most JSON Libraries.[3]

```
try(InputStream in=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("YourJsonFile")){
//pass InputStream to JSON-Library, e.g. using Jackson
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(in, JsonNode.class);
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
}
catch(Exception e){
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

[1] [Different ways of loading a file as an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream)

[2] [Try With Resources vs Try-Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516020/try-with-resources-vs-try-catch)

[3] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

**Hint:** Don't try to use this method from within a `parallelStream` or similar. It will result in an exception.

Comment: just wrote this created jsonNode as string.

json = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);

Thanks

Comment: This does not work in an Enum initializer block, but replacing the try resource with `InputStream json = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(templateFile)`  works in that case.

Answer (score 14):

Move json to a file `someName.json` in resources folder.

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Headphones",
  price: 1250.0,
  tags: [
    "home",
    "green"
  ]
}
```

Read the json file like

```java
File file = new File(
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("someName.json").getFile()
    );
```

Further you can use `file` object however you want to use. you can convert to a json object using your favourite json library.

For eg. using Jackson you can do

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SomeClass someClassObj = mapper.readValue(file, SomeClass.class);
```

Comment: Please note that this approach won't work if you build your code into .jar. Use reading through input stream (for example, see the answer to this question by @jschnasse https://stackoverflow.com/a/59677244/1559962)

Comment: elegant way of using it @Smile

Answer (score 12):

There are many possible ways of doing this:

**Read the file completely** *(only suitable for smaller files)*

```
public static String readFileFromResources(String filename) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    URL resource = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename);  
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(resource.toURI()));  
    return new String(bytes);  
}
```

**Read in the file line by line** *(also suitable for larger files)*

```
private static String readFileFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {
    URL resource = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);

    if (resource == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file is not found!");

    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(resource.getFile())));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return fileContent.toString();
}
```

**The most comfortable way is to use [apache-commons.io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)**

```
private static String readFileFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return IOUtils.resourceToString(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: resourceToString has error? It says cannot find declaration to go to

Answer (score 4):

Pass your file-path with from resources:

Example: If your `resources -> folder_1 -> filename.json` Then pass in

```
String json = getResource("folder_1/filename.json");
```

```
public String getResource(String resource) {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource)),
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                json.append(str);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Caught exception reading resource " + resource, e);
        }
        return json.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is JSON.simple is lightweight JSON processing library which can be used to read JSON or write JSON file.Try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader("test.json")) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the json file and converting into object using **Jackson** Mapper.

```
  public OldPromotionElements parseOldElements()
{
    File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Test.json").getFile());
   try {
      OldPromotionElements oldPromotionElements;
      ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
      oldPromotionElements = objectMapper.readValue(file, OldPromotionElements.class);
    }
   catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
    }
 return oldPromotionElements;
 }
```

[reference link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access)