# Spring boot app deployment issue - cant not access file from classpath after package mvn jar

Tags: spring-boot, java-ee-7

Im working on a project with spring boot. After finish this project and package with mvn install in order to get my compiled jar file, i get some issue during the exploitation.

Some controller on my app need to get files or file path from classpath by using

```
String filePath = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:file.json").getPath()
```

this method work until i package to jar

Same issue to access properties files from classpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOException when reading JSON file from resources in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703834/ioexception-when-reading-json-file-from-resources-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your approach will work from an IDE but for the jar it won't find the file. So use code like below to get it worked.

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("file.json").getFile();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot) are some different ways to achieve the same.

Comment: thank for your help. but this method work also only in my IDE. after package to the jar, i still get issue. java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [file.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Desktop/myapp/target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/file.json